# GKE: get a command which pod is running

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

Is there a way to get a command and image which the pod is running in GKE? To my knowledge `kubectl` does not have this facility. Maybe it's possible to do so with some dedicated `gcloud` tool? `docker ps`, `kubectl exec ps` is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Did you really just need the `kubectl describe` command? I would have thought you already tried that and didn't get the info you need.
This'd make the post pretty much a duplicate. I'm sure there are other posts explaining the use of the `kubectl describe` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl` gives you a variety of options, among those is `describe`, which let's you get the information you are looking for like so:

```
$ kubectl describe pods etcd-minikube
Name:                 etcd-minikube
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000001000
Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
Node:                 minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:           Fri, 21 Apr 2023 14:57:11 +0200
Labels:               component=etcd
                      tier=control-plane
Annotations:          kubeadm.kubernetes.io/etcd.advertise-client-urls: https://192.168.49.2:2379
                      kubernetes.io/config.hash: 9d3d310935e5fabe942511eec3e2cd0c
                      kubernetes.io/config.mirror: 9d3d310935e5fabe942511eec3e2cd0c
                      kubernetes.io/config.seen: 2023-04-21T12:57:10.854200840Z
                      kubernetes.io/config.source: file
                      seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
Status:               Running
SeccompProfile:       RuntimeDefault
IP:                   192.168.49.2
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.49.2
Controlled By:  Node/minikube
Containers:
  etcd:
    Container ID:  docker://172b7490d79dcb36f2c81e3ce82611b18c09f128b5030c7b225636b345d5c7d4
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.5.1-0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/etcd@sha256:64b9ea357325d5db9f8a723dcf503b5a449177b17ac87d69481e126bb724c263
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      etcd
      --advertise-client-urls=https://192.168.49.2:2379
      --cert-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/server.crt
      --client-cert-auth=true
      --data-dir=/var/lib/minikube/etcd
      --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://192.168.49.2:2380
      --initial-cluster=minikube=https://192.168.49.2:2380
      --key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/server.key
      --listen-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://192.168.49.2:2379
      --listen-metrics-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2381
      --listen-peer-urls=https://192.168.49.2:2380
      --name=minikube
      --peer-cert-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.crt
      --peer-client-cert-auth=true
      --peer-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.key
      --peer-trusted-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt
      --proxy-refresh-interval=70000
      --snapshot-count=10000
      --trusted-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt
```

If you need to access things programmatically, you can also use `get` and json format the output to then pipe into utilities like `jq` like so:

```
$ kubectl get pod etcd-minikube -o json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubeadm.kubernetes.io/etcd.advertise-client-urls": "https://192.168.49.2:2379",
            "kubernetes.io/config.hash": "9d3d310935e5fabe942511eec3e2cd0c",
            "kubernetes.io/config.mirror": "9d3d310935e5fabe942511eec3e2cd0c",
            "kubernetes.io/config.seen": "2023-04-21T12:57:10.854200840Z",
            "kubernetes.io/config.source": "file",
            "seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod": "runtime/default"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-04-21T12:57:11Z",
        "labels": {
            "component": "etcd",
            "tier": "control-plane"
        },
        "name": "etcd-minikube",
        "namespace": "kube-system",
        "ownerReferences": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "controller": true,
                "kind": "Node",
                "name": "minikube",
                "uid": "cfe42b77-7cfc-4248-af39-1dec62196242"
            }
        ],
        "resourceVersion": "294",
        "uid": "58dced46-2ac0-4986-bced-5e7f9a097cf9"
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "command": [
                    "etcd",
                    "--advertise-client-urls=https://192.168.49.2:2379",
                    "--cert-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/server.crt",
                    "--client-cert-auth=true",
                    "--data-dir=/var/lib/minikube/etcd",
                    "--initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://192.168.49.2:2380",
                    "--initial-cluster=minikube=https://192.168.49.2:2380",
                    "--key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/server.key",
                    "--listen-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://192.168.49.2:2379",
                    "--listen-metrics-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2381",
                    "--listen-peer-urls=https://192.168.49.2:2380",
                    "--name=minikube",
                    "--peer-cert-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.crt",
                    "--peer-client-cert-auth=true",
                    "--peer-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.key",
                    "--peer-trusted-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt",
                    "--proxy-refresh-interval=70000",
                    "--snapshot-count=10000",
                    "--trusted-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt"
                ],
```

If for a given image that a pod uses, you would like to get the command of the actual container image and not the one that is passed via its spec, you can use the information about the image and then docker inspect. The following image is deployed as per the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/), so it does not have a command in the spec but still runs nginx.

Get the right pods (they are both the same in our case)

```
$ kubectl get pods | grep nginx
nginx-deployment-9456bbbf9-gqzhp   1/1     Running   0             10m
nginx-deployment-9456bbbf9-lthrc   1/1     Running   0             10m
```

Use one of them and get the container image:

```
$ kubectl get pod nginx-deployment-9456bbbf9-gqzhp -o jsonpath="{.spec.containers[*].image}"
nginx:1.14.2
```

Use `docker image inspect` to analyze the image (not that you have to have it pulled)

```
$ docker pull nginx:1.14.2
1.14.2: Pulling from library/nginx
007027d142c8: Pull complete
925342e1fcde: Pull complete
668b9ac9804b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f7988fb6c02e0ce69257d9bd9cf37ae20a60f1df7563c3a2a6abe24160306b8d
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:1.14.2
docker.io/library/nginx:1.14.2

$ docker image inspect nginx:1.14.2
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:7bbc8783b8ecfdb6453396805cc0fb5fcdaf1b16cbb907c8ab1b8685732d50a4",
        "RepoTags": [
            "nginx:1.14.2"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "nginx@sha256:f7988fb6c02e0ce69257d9bd9cf37ae20a60f1df7563c3a2a6abe24160306b8d"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2019-03-27T09:51:29.346495571Z",
        "Container": "877b55d528f890d650358f37048a361f24b8c4d1e414c79e4d2c82bb8d186310",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "877b55d528f8",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.14.2-1~stretch",
                "NJS_VERSION=1.14.2.0.2.6-1~stretch"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"nginx\" \"-g\" \"daemon off;\"]"
```

Now make it a one-line using `jq`:

```
$ docker pull $(kubectl get pod nginx-deployment-9456bbbf9-gqzhp -o jsonpath="{.spec.containers[*].image}") && docker image inspect $(kubectl get pod nginx-deployment-9456bbbf9-gqzhp -o jsonpath="{.spec.containers[*].image}") | jq .[].ContainerConfig.Cmd
1.14.2: Pulling from library/nginx
Digest: sha256:f7988fb6c02e0ce69257d9bd9cf37ae20a60f1df7563c3a2a6abe24160306b8d
Status: Image is up to date for nginx:1.14.2
docker.io/library/nginx:1.14.2
[
  "/bin/sh",
  "-c",
  "#(nop) ",
  "CMD [\"nginx\" \"-g\" \"daemon off;\"]"
]
```

Comment: maybe `etcd` pod does display the command it is running but not all pods do. for eg. a simple `nginx` pod. How about in that scenario? I thought that would have been the OP's original problem.

Comment: same. I just took a system pod to show that even those are doing it. Ever command that you give to a pod via its spec will work like this. What you don't get is the CMD/ENTRYPOINT of the container image itself

Comment: By writing 'even those' , I would assume you mean all pods display that information which command they are running. Is that so?

Comment: Every command they are given via the spec, yes. I extended with a way to get the command in the actual container image

Comment: Downloading the image to run the inspect was the only reason for me to not mention that as an answer. I can imagine one would not wanna download images for this purpose but I totally get your point of view - pretty much aligned with mine. I can't think of a way to find that without downloading the image or having the Dockerfile. Do share if you can think of one

Comment: you could try to run the docker command on the host where the pod is running, but I would strongly advice against that because either you have to log in to the host via CLI or you have to mount the host file system and both options aren't great. Not judging but _normally_ I'd hope people don't blind run container images they don't know and so at least know what the base image is doing ;)

Comment: True, but that is what the OP needed to know and as mentioned `docker ps` and `kubectl exec` weren't an option. So I'm assuming login to the host should probably be off-limits too. Strange one rather. Thanks for the discussion, let's park it here. Good day!